# How do I define Grid structure for this Data Template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following data template as described in this prototype

[image]

The lines are just there as guides, they are not drawn.

I used the following code and failed miserably

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Update" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It overlapped things and looked funny. Help me get the understanding of this straight. I thought Width 2* for left column and 1* for right column would mean Left column is double in width as right column. Is that not true ?

Comment: But you don't have a 1* for the right column? And why the * for row height?  And it is 0 based - you don't have a Grid.Row="2"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're counting `Columns`/`Rows` number from 1 when you should start from 0. Also, if I am not wrong, `Button` should span across 2 rows:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="Install" />
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="Update" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description}" />
</Grid>
```

And why would you have height = *
Auto makes more sense to me
And a button with fixed content - why not a width of Auto

Comment: How can we have update button right-aligned to the Grid regardless of size of content ? I used your code; the Update button is not right-aligned.

Comment: You don't show how the template is being applied.  I suspect you need a horizontalcontentallignment = stretch.  I think that is a new question.